# Why I can create instance of case class in scala without new operator?

Tags: scala

Why it is possible to create instance of a `case class` in scala without `new` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
class C(arg: Int)
object C {
  def apply(i: Int): C = new C(i)
}

val c = C(99)
```

A `case` class automatically creates the companion `object` with the factory method via `apply()`.